# Turn out all the lights and call on the Lord

Tags: expressions

A man I knew, born in 1921, used to enter a room at festive gatherings and say "Turn out all the lights and call on the Lord." Do you know the origin of that phrase, or do you think it was just an idiosyncrasy of his?

Comment: Literally the only place this appears on a Google search is your post here, so I think it was his alone.

Comment: He could have heard a certain James Brown song, and be misquoting for his own amusement: "Cut off the lights/And call the law" (Funky Drummer, 1970)

Comment: Sounds like an idiotsyncrazy to me.

Comment: @jimm101 or maybe the other people didn't post it on the internet? Especially considering the internet wasn't around for a long time.

Comment: @JJJ True, but the Internet is littered with lots of things that predate it.

Answer (score 1):

**Turn out all the lights and call on the Lord** appears to be as you said, **idiosyncratic**.  His own 'turn of words'. I can find no registry listing for the same, nor anything close.  I suspect his intention was meant 'to focus on said deity'!